# Design a Regular expression for 10 alphanumeric digits

Tags: regex

I want a regular expression for using it in ASP.NET. It should be of 10 alphanumeric digits. The first 5 characters are letters, next 4 numerals and last character letter.

Comment: Regex lesson 0: `\w{5}\d{4}\w`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that should do the trick

```
^[a-zA-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[a-zA-Z]$
```

Comment: You can edit it to accept A-Z.